# CSS Page Position Issue

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, position, screen

On my website https://www.hcldesign.co.uk/ you can see that I have a top banner.
This banner has a button saying 'see website example' and when this is pressed it changes the slide image. Now this also causes a weird screen position glitch with my navbar and content/body section.

When you click the button you can see a gap appears on the left of the body and pushes some content to the right by a few pixels and then flicks back. The position of the navbar also does the same when the button on the slider/banner is clicked.

I have tried messing with the position code for some of the elements but can't seem to fix this.

I need to keep the page content in the same position when the button is clicked.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D is right. Nevertheless I found a solution to your problem.

Comment: Hi, I apologize about the question format, I really did not see what code I could add into the question that would be useful that I knew about. But thanks your solution works great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its caused by this CSS rule:

```
.ls-overflow-hidden {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

This class is added to your `<body>` element when clicking "see website example". Change the value to i.e. `overflow: auto;` and the glitch should be gone.

Answer (score -1):

On clicking the button of the slider .ls-overflow-hidden class is added to the body. You can fix it by the css rule

```
body.ls-overflow-hidden {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: How is this answer different from mine?

Comment: I haven't said your answer is wrong at all. The only thing is that ls-overflow-hidden can be a generic class it could have been used elsewhere, using it without the body tag can change its use elsewhere also.

Comment: Ok sure. But that would have been a comment, not a copied answer... Thanks for the hint anyway.